# How do I select a date BETWEEN dates from two columns?

Tags: sql

This select not work:

```
SELECT collaborators.fullname, learnings.state_id, orgs.name AS orgs_name, courses.name AS courses_name
FROM learnings
LEFT JOIN collaborators ON learnings.person_id = collaborators.id
LEFT JOIN orgs ON collaborators.org_id = orgs.id
LEFT JOIN courses ON learnings.course_id = courses.id
WHERE collaborators.org_id = :org_id
AND learnings.start_date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2
AND learnings.finish_date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2
```

if you leave one of the following in the request:

```
AND learnings.start_date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2
```

or

```
AND learnings.finish_date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2
```

then the selection works.
please tell me:
How to combine two columns in this query `start_date` and `finish_date` and filter them as one?

Comment: Please explain "not work".  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want any overlap between the two time periods then you can use:

```
AND
learnings.start_date <= :date2 AND
learnings.finish_date >= :date1
```

If you want one time period to be completely inside the other -- say, the `learnings` time stamp completed inside the two dates -- you would use:

```
AND
learnings.start_date >= :date1 AND
learnings.finish_date <= :date2
```